# Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark 'async start' does not exist

Tags: javascript, performance, async-await, latency

I want to measure the performance(latency) of my async function.

**checkout.js**

```
export const renderButton: RenderButtonAPIExternalFunction = function(): void | ButtonObject {
    performance.mark(button_render_start);
    buttonUIRender(); 
}

export async function buttonUIRender() {
        await buttonUIRenderer.renderButton();
        performance.mark(button_render_finish);
        performance.measure(
            button_render_measure,
            button_render_start,
            button_render_finish
        );
}
```

I have the above logic written to measure the performance. However, I am getting an error saying `Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark button_render_start does not exist`. Do performance measures not work with async functions?

Comment: what are the values of those variables? `button_render_*` and `maxoPerformance`

Comment: `renderButton` does not return a promise, so why would you `await` it?

Comment: What is `maxoPerformance`?

Comment: maxoPerformance is `performance`, I misspelled it. `button_render_* `are strings which are the names of the marks. I need to `await renderButton` because I need some logic executed after `renderButton`.

Comment: If `renderButton` is synchronous, you don't need to `await` it, code execution is sequential by default. If `renderButton` is doing something asynchronous, you must make it return a promise, as otherwise the waiting won't work.

Comment: so `buttonUIRenderer.renderButton()` is asynchronous, but `renderButton` is not? ... by the way, that code block for `export const renderButton` is invalid - perhaps you can now show the real code, since this code won't even parse, let alone run

Comment: updated the code block above. Also, yes `buttonUIRenderer.renderButton()` is asynchronous, but `renderButton` is not